# Marker window in google maps API displays full screen size

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with a window info in my google maps android api. So everything works fine, shows at the right moment etc, just when I display the actual "window" layout item it always displays as a whole activity window (too big, instead of a small brick determined in design). Where can be the mistake? I attach the code from activity (adapter) and the layout. I crossed out confidential parts of code.

```
@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
  View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_event_map_window, null);
     for(int i= 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        if(markers[i].getId().equals(marker.getId())) {
        //Setting data in the window - works correctly
          return v;
                }
            };
 mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
 mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
 mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(infoWindowAdapter);
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:background="@color/background_app_color">

<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/textDistance"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Distance"
 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
 android:layout_below="@+id/textStartDate"
 android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textStartDate"
 android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textStartDate" />
 <ImageView
  android:layout_width="160dp"
  android:layout_height="160dp"
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
  android:id="@+id/downloaded_image"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textEventName"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Event Name"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
  android:layout_alignTop="@+id/downloaded_image"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/downloaded_image"
  android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/downloaded_image"
  android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
  android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />
 </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance,
John